# What do I need to open on my Windows Firewall to allow GFI Security Endpoint functionality

Tags: windows, security, firewall, windows-firewall

I've been asked to switch off my firewall so that GFI Security Endpoint will work properly, I'm not switching off my firewall!

What do I need to do on my windows firewall to allow GFI Security Endpoint functionality?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A search of GFI's knowledge base using the search term "firewall ports" and the product limited to "EndPoint Security" returned the information below ([article](http://kb.gfi.com/articles/SkyNet_Article/What-are-the-default-ports-used-by-GFI-EndPointSecurity?retURL=/apex/SupportHome&popup=true)). The first two entries apply to the agent installed on client computers while the last option applies to the actual server portion.

Agent Communication: TCP 1116

When the agent is installed, the GFI EndPointSecurity Agent Service communicates back to port 1116 on the GFI EndPointSecurity Console server.  This can be changed in Configuration > Advanced Options > Communication.

Agent installation and updating: TCP 135, 139 & 445

When the GFI EndPointSecurity Console machine installs or updates agents, it communicates from a random port to port 139 & 445 on the target agent machine. These are the standard SMB /RPC ports enabled on the clients by Microsoft File and Folder Sharing.

SQL Server Communications: 1433

The GFI EndPointSecurity Console server connects to the Microsoft SQL Server service instance on the SQL Server machine. This is normally TCP 1433, but may be configured differently on the SQL Server (it can be a dynamically assigned port or statically defined).

Comment: Cheers, only other thing I needed to do was turn on File and Printer sharing!